# Coherent objects in a hypercomplete $\infty$-topos

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, infinity-topos-theory

In Lurie's "Spectral Algebraic Geometry", Proposition A.6.6.1 (2) shows that for $\mathcal{X}$ an $\infty$-topos that is both locally coherent and hypercomplete, the full subcategory $\mathcal{X}^{coh}$ spanned by the coherent objects is essentially small. I will not go too deeply into the proof of this statement, as it uses a lengthy recognition criterion for coherent objects (Prop. A.6.5.7), but the main point is that the presentability ensures the existence of an essentially small subcategory $\mathcal{X}_0$ of $\mathcal{X}$ such that every object of $\mathcal{X}$ can be covered by objects of it; and local coherence makes it possible to choose $\mathcal{X}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{X}^{coh}$ so that we can further go on to enlarge it as to fill $\mathcal{X}^{coh}$ up completely.

In Warning A.6.6.2, Lurie claims that "using a more refined argument", one could show that the local coherence of $\mathcal{X}$ could be dropped in this statement, namely every hypercomplete $\infty$-topos has an essentially small subcategory of coherent objects; but this hypercompleteness condition can't be dropped: A counterexample would be the Tangent topos of the $\infty$-category of Spaces $\mathcal{X} = \operatorname{Exc}^1(\mathcal{S}_*^{fin}, \mathcal{S})$, whose objects can be identified with pairs $(X,E)$ of $X \in \mathcal{S}$, $E$ a local system of spectra on $X$. The coherent objects here are, as one can show, exactly those pairs $(X,E)$ where $X$ is coherent as a space; and since the $\infty$-category of spectra is not essentially small, the subcategory of those can't be as well.

However concerning the first claim of the Warning, namely the "more refined argument" that Lurie is talking about, I have no idea how this argument would look like. It sounds like the above argument could somehow be saved, but I think the remarks I gave above make clear why this isn't a very straightforward task - does anyone know how this works?

Comment: If $x \in \mathcal X$ is coherent, then does the Postnikov tower for $X$ converge? If so, then you could imagine proving this by showing inductively that any $(n+1)$-topos only has a set of $n$-coherent objects. E.g. it sounds tractable to me to show that in a 1-topos, there's only a set of quasicompact objects.

Comment: @TimCampion Thanks for the idea! I have thought about it and agree that your argument should work, if the statement about Postnikov towers converging for coherent objects holds. However, that does indeed seem like a lot to ask (of course, it is wrong in non-hypercomplete $\infty$-topoi like the Tangent topos above) - I am not sure. By the way, I also checked Lurie's proof again and it is really just the covering argument above that goes wrong, so saving that would also be an option.

Comment: @TimCampion I think your conjecture about Postnikov completenes is unfortunately wrong, a colleague has found the following counterexample: Take the profinite (thus coherent) topos $\operatorname{Sh}_{\operatorname{eff}}(\Pi_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/2)$, this is hypercomplete by [this paper](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/K-theory/305/nowmovo.pdf), see also [here](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/4714/postnikov-towers-and-hypercompletion/).

Comment: The former paper also constructs, in 2.1.30, the object $\Gamma^*(\Pi_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \operatorname{K}(\mathbb{Z}/2,n))$ where $\Gamma^*$ is the left adjoint of the global sections functor, and shows that it is not Postnikov-complete. However, it is coherent, as by SAG E.3.1.2 $\Gamma^*$ preserves coherence in this case and the homotopy groups of the given product are finite.